# Trailing slash using react router is causing incorrect rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route that I´m using to catch all

```
<Route path="/:path" exact strict component={MyComponent} />
<Route path="/backend/users" exact strict component={MyUserComponent} />
```

and when I go to */whatever* it renders **MyComponent**
but if I go to */whatever/* is rendering **MyUserComponent**

Question is: how to change the first route to match */whatever* and */whatever/*

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `strict` prop as per the docs.

> When true, a path that has a trailing slash will only match a location.pathname with a trailing slash.

https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Route/strict-bool